# Why can't create superuser

Tags: django, duplicates, command, admin, superuser

how can I solve this problem in django[duplicate admin showing][1]

"raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: admin"

Comment: like the error said, you have duplicate apps name `admin`, show us the installed_app section of your settings file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.